# Call function stream2 and stream3

Tags: matlab

I have a question, for `stream2` and `stream3`, really need to call with `streamline((X,Y,U,V,STARTX,STARTY))`, and `streamline(stream3(X,Y,Z,U,V,W,STARTX,STARTY,STARTZ))`?

My stream2:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:5,0:0.1:5);
U=X; V=-Y;
startx = 0.1:0.1:1;
starty = ones(1 ,length(startx));
stream2(X,Y,U,V,startx,starty);
```

Comment: no, you dont need to call them with `streamline`. Streamline plots them, stream2/strem3 computes them

Comment: Ok, but for me work, when I call with 'streamline', if I don't use this function, my axes are empty.

Comment: That is not the whole data. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Ok, this is the whole data `[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:5,0:0.1:5);
U=X;
V=-Y;
startx = 0.1:0.1:1;
starty = ones(1 ,length(startx));
stream2(X,Y,U,V,startx,starty);`

Comment: Ok, I edited the post.

Comment: Your code does not call `streamline`. I suggest you read my first commment

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you.